# Navigation menu hides behind content

Tags: html, css

I keep having this issue where my CSS dropdown menu is hiding behind my content on my page. I have looked around and tried using Z-Index in order to specify where it needs to go, and I cannot figure it out. All of my content is in the div class ".wrapper" which is what the navigation line is hiding behind. Here is the CSS:

```
 nav {
    margin: -75px 100px 20px 100px;
    text-align: right;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1000;
}

nav ul ul {
    display: none;
}

    nav ul li:hover > ul {
        display: block;
        position: absolute;
        z-index: 1000;
    }


nav ul {
    background: #efefef; 
    background: linear-gradient(top, #D22525 0%, #5F1414 100%);
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #D22525 0%, #5F1414 100%);
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #D22525 0%,#5F1414 100%);
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 9px rgba(0,0,0,0.15);
    padding: 0 20px;
    border-radius: 10px;  
    list-style: none;
    position: relative;
    display: inline-table;
}
    nav ul:after {
        content: ""; clear: both; display: block;
    }

    nav ul li {
        float: left;
    }
        nav ul li:hover {
            background: #4b545f;
            background: linear-gradient(top, #4f5964 0%, #5f6975 40%);
            background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #4f5964 0%, #5f6975 40%);
            background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #4f5964 0%,#5f6975 40%);
        }
            nav ul li:hover a {
                color: #fff;
            }

        nav ul li a {
            display: block; padding: 25px 40px;
            color: #FFF; text-decoration: none;
        }


    nav ul ul {
        background: #5f6975; border-radius: 0px; padding: 0;
        position: absolute; top: 100%;z-index: 1000;
    }
        nav ul ul li {
            float: none; 
            border-top: 1px solid #6b727c;
            border-bottom: 1px solid #575f6a; position: relative;
            z-index: 1000;
        }
            nav ul ul li a {
                padding: 15px 40px;
                color: #fff;
            }   
                nav ul ul li a:hover {
                    background: #4b545f;
                }

    nav ul ul ul {
        position: absolute; left: 100%; top:0;
    }

    .wrapper
    {
        overflow: hidden;
        padding: 0em 0em 5em 0em;
        background: #FFF;
        top: 150px;
        position: absolute;
        z-index: 0;
    }
```

After that Here is my HTML:

```
<body>
<div id="header-wrapper">
    <div id="header" class="container">
        <div id="logo">
<h1></span><a href="/">HHS E3</a></h1>
</div>
<nav>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="/"><img src="/media/home.png" height="14px" /></a></li>
        <li><a>Media</a>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="/media/videos">Videos</a></li>
        <li><a href="/media/pictures">Pictures</a></li>
        <li><a href="/media/music">Music</a></li>
    </ul>
        <li><a>Bullying</a>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="/bullying/harrassment">Harrassment</a></li>
        <li><a href="/bullying/abuse">Abuse</a></li>
        <li><a href="/bullying/mental">Mental Illness</a></li>
        <li><a href="/bullying/dissability">Dissability</a></li>
        <li><a href="/bullying/fun">For Fun</a></li>
    </ul>
    </li>
        <li><a>About E3</a>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="/about/stories">Our Videos & Stories</a></li>
        <li><a href="/about/presentations">Our Presentations</a></li>
    </ul>
    </li>
        <li><a>About the Founders</a>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="/about/radio">Raider Radio</a></li>
        <li><a href="/about/video">Video</a></li>
        <li><a href="/about/info">Info</a></li>


<?php
    if(empty($_SESSION['logged_in']))
    {

    } else {
        echo "<li><a href='#'>User</a><ul><li><a href='/upload'>Upload</a></li><li><a href='/logout.php'>Logout</a></li></ul></li>";
    }
    ?>
    </ul>
</nav>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="wrapper">
    <div id="three-column" class="container">
```

If anyone has any thoughts on what I need to fix, I would greatly appreciate it. Overall, the drop down menus work, but only the first row is displayed and the rest are hidden behind the wrapper. Do I maybe need to do anything to the id="three-column" or class="container" Thanks!

PS: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/NyqqM/)

Comment: Linking to a working example would help us help you.  But you have a negative `margin-top` on `nav` element which would pull the `nav` up and you have `overflow: hidden;` on the `.wrapper`.  It could be possible that the `nav` is pulled up out of the visible area of the `.wrapper`.  Try setting `overflow: visible;` on the `.wrapper`.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/NyqqM/1/ on FF mac, I don't see any issues, which browser are you seeing this on? Also it's kind of strange that your content is positioned absolutely. Hard to tell why with the given incomplete code

Comment: Bad code, didnt find the issue!

Comment: So far, I have tried everything you guys said, no luck.

Answer (score 1):

**[Here's a fiddle!](http://jsfiddle.net/MathiasaurusRex/bRyB2/)**

I did three things:

1. Removed the margin from the Nav (The margins + the background was covering your logo)
2. Added display: inline-block to both the Nav and #logo. This allowed them to display next to each other correctly.
3. Added float:left and `float:right` to the `#logo` and Nav respectively. Which would push them to the left and right.

   `nav{
     text-align: right;
     position: relative;
     z-index: 1000;
     float:right;
     display: inline-block;
     float: right;
    }`

   `#logo{
     display: inline-block;
     float: left;
    }`

Comment: You are almost there bud. Good job. But if you resize the screen it still renders behind. But again, kudos to you for taking the time. His markup is so undone :)

Comment: @LOTUSMS Nope. When you resize the screen the nav element shifts under the logo element. Which is where you would throw in a media query, but  that's another topic!

Answer (score 0):

Try this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/39james/p9zQy/)

I used your html and css and made the below changes:

1. Added `position:relative` to `nav ul li`
2. Changed `top` value to 70px in `nav ul ul`

Hope this helps you.

Answer (score 0):

I would like to say thank you to everyone for starters. I have read every comment and answer on here. However, there was one thing I caught by putting essentially all of your answers together. I had forgotten to place the div id "header-wrapper" in my code shown above. In it, like one user had stated, it had `Overflow: Hidden` The nav was contained in there. After setting `Overflow: Visible` my issue has been resolved. Thank you again everyone.